# Getting blank attachment for generated pdf in codeigniter by mPdf

Tags: codeigniter-2

Here is my function.I m generating a pdf and trying to mail it. I have checked my email library which is working fine but gives blank attachment for generated  pdf.

```php
function voucherEmail()
{

    $this->load->library('m_pdf');

    ob_start();

    $day = date('d');
    $year = date('Y');
    $month = date('F');

    echo "Hello World Today is $month $day, $year";

    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML(($html));

    $content = $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('','S');

    $filename = "giftVoucher.pdf";

    $config = array();
    $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['protocol']            = "sendmail";
    $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
    $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
    $config['mailtype']            = "html";
    $config['charset']             = "iso-8859-1";


    $this->load->library('email',$config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('voucher@theholidaysclubs.com', 'The Holidays Club:Gift Voucher');
    $this->email->to('shikhachauhan862@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('The Holidays Club:Gift Voucher');
    $this->email->attach($content,'attachment',$filename,'application/pdf');
    $this->email->send(); 

}
```

Can someone please where I am going wrong

Comment: Why double parenthesis  `$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML(($html));` ??

Comment: Why don't you try `$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($filepath.$filename, "F");` ??

Comment: tried that solution also....not working